# Methods in Odoo Studio

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I know to make a method in odoo and how to call the method through a button but with odoo studio I am not finding features in make a method and call it through a button. So my question is How to make a method in Odoo studio and call it through a button?